# Testcase in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I have written a testcase for a function in Collection class in smalltalk visualworks.
the function code is as follows:

```
valuesBetween: a and: b
| array1 arraysize |
arraysize := self size.
"array1:=nil."
array1 := ((1 to: arraysize) select: [:k | k >= a & (k <= b)])
            collect: [:k | self at: k].
^array1
```

and testcase code is:

```
       testvaluesbetween 
       |test1|
       test1:=#(1 2 3 4 5 6).
       self assert: test1 valuesBetween:2 and:4=#(2 3 4).
```

can anyone help me in this as this test is not working.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What does the debugger say? Something like:

> MessageNotUnderstood: YourTestCase>>assert:valuesBetween:and:

Try with parentheses like this:

```
self assert: ((test1 valuesBetween: 2 and: 4) = #(2 3 4))
```

Comment: But rather say `self assert: #(2 3 4) equals: (test1 valuesBetween: 2 and: 4)` because the error message is much better.